# Which of the following is true about $m \times n $ matrix of rank $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Let $A $ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n$ with real entries. Choose the correct statement.

1.$Ax=b$ has a solution for any $b$.

2.$Ax=0$ does not have a solution.

3.if $Ax=b$ has a solution then it is unique.

4.$y'A=0$ for some nonzero $y'$ where $y'$ is transpose of vector $y$

Now option 2 can be rejected because there is always $ x=0$.For option 3 if I take example \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} and take $x _ (1\times 1) $ and taking $b$ aby vector then I get option 3 RIGHT.  Am I right?  And I want to know how to Answer it in more general way. Thanks very much  in Advance

Comment: Since $rank(A)\leq \text{min}(m,n)$, we know that $n\leq m$.  In the case that $n=m$ then (3) happens to be true, however this is false when $n<m$.  (2) does as you say have the trivial solution, but since the rank implies the columns of $A$ are linearly independent its *only* solution is the trivial solution, so (2) would be correct if changed to read "does not have a solution except the trivial solution."  (1) is false when n<m.  (4) happens to be false when $n=m$, but will be true for $n<m$.

Comment: All of these observations come from [The Fundamental Subspaces Theorem](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/newpaper_ver3.pdf) relating the rank to the nullity of a matrix (as well as dimension of dimension of left-nullspace).  In my opinion, all options are false.  If (2) is changed as suggested, then (2) would be the most correct answer.